# Extract lines from multiple text filenames and then pull those lines from a textfile - Linux

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed

My problem is I need to extract the line number from the end of a bunch of textfiles names with a size greater than 0. Once I have the list of line numbers, I need to extract the lines from the master text file.

I figured out how to do the first step using the below command which finds all files containing the .sh.e with a size of > 0 bytes, It then pulls the last few characters contianing the jobID and an sed command strips off the leading 7 characters  (this can probably be done a little more elegantly too) which then gives us a nice list of line numbers.

Filename Examples:

```
Job_2017-09-25-08-50-28-ahill.sh.e1191.92
Job_2017-09-25-08-50-28-ahill.sh.e1191.102
Job_2017-09-25-08-50-28-ahill.sh.e1191.252
Job_2017-09-25-08-50-28-ahill.sh.e1191.301

find . -name "*.sh.e*" -type f -size +0c | grep -E -o ".e1191.{0,10}" | sed 's/^.\{7\}//'

92
102
252
301
```

I then need to extract the lines from a textfile which tells me the original file location of my jobs.

I am having trouble passing this to sed or awk to parse the master log. I have tried the following:

```
find . -name "*.sh.e*" -type f -size +0c | grep -E -o ".e1191.{0,10}" | awk (NR=sed s/^.\{7\}//) ../temp/files.2017-09-26.txt

find . -name "*.sh.e*" -type f -size +0c | grep -E -o ".e1191.{0,10}" | sed -n "$(sed 's/^.\{7\}//')p" ../temp/files.2017-09-26.txt

find . -name "*.sh.e*" -type f -size +0c | grep -E -o ".e1191.{0,10}" | awk "NR==$(sed 's/^.\{7\}//')" ../temp/files.2017-09-26.txt
```

All seem to fail or give an expression error. I can do it in Excel for now, but would like to do this from the command line as I have to do it often.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: this phrase "I then need to extract the lines from a textfile which tells me the original file location of my jobs. " is unclear. What should be the final result?

Comment: The final result is a list of string(s) at line(s) X (that we got from the first command) from the ../temp/files.2017-09-26.txt file. Which is a large list of paths to the original WAV files.

Comment: so each time the script should search the file `/temp/files.2017-09-26.txt` for numbers `92`, `102` etc. and output the matching lines containing those numbers?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: @MasaAsh There is a difference between lines matching containig the numbers and the numbers being the line number which need to be extracted, you should clarify this point

Comment: elaborate your condition: you have wrote *to extract the lines from a textfile* OR you meant the **numbers** of lines?

Comment: The numbers are line numbers from "files.2017-09-26.txt". Not lines (strings) containing these numbers in "files.2017-09-26.txt".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimized and fast **find** solution:

```
find . -type f -name "*.sh.e[0-9]*" -size +0c -exec sh -c 'fn=$1; n=${fn##*.}; \
        sed -n "$n p" ../temp/files.2017-09-26.txt' _ {} \;
```

---

- `fn=$1` - `fn` variable is assigned with filename returned by *find* command
- `n=${fn##*.}` - extracting the needed numeric suffix from the filename (i.e. `92`, `102` etc)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what he wanted to accomplish anymore, the suffix retrieved isn't the line number to extract? it's just a grep on these numbers?

Comment: @Esteban, see comments under the question

Comment: I know, but he said 2 times (one in the question, and one in the first comment), that it was line number, so I think he misundestood what you implied by "matching lines"

Comment: Right. The first extraction command gives me the actual line number from the "files.2017-09-26.txt". A reference to this number does not need to be grep'd from this file. I need to extract the string AT this row.

Comment: Yours is giving me all 930 lines. Thank-you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Not the prettiest command, but it should work :

```
sed -n $(find . -name "*.sh.e*" -type f  -size +0c |rev |cut -d'.' -f1 | tr "\n" " " | sed -e 's/ /p;/g' -e 's/;$//g') < ../temp/files.2017-09-26.txt
```

What it does :

- `find . -name "*.sh.e*" -type f  -size +0c` : List the files
- `rev` : reverse the letters of the file name
- `cut -d'.' -f1` : cut the first field delimited by `.` : ie. the lines
- `tr "\n" " "` : replace the new line by a space
- `sed 's/ /p;/g'` : replace the spaces by `p;`
- `sed 's/;$//g'` : strip the last `;`^

It create the pattern needed by the `sed -n 'np;mp' < file.txt` command, where `n` and `m` are line number

Comment: I have 930 results and your command only seems to be listing 850 of them.

    find . -name "*.sh.e*" -type f  -size +0c | wc -l
    930

Not sure why.

Comment: I don't know where the error could occur without file sample. I mocked up the command with 2 files and a log of 5 lines ;). You could try to execute a sed on each file to first test the command, something like :

Comment: @MasaAsh `find . -name "*.sh.e*" -type f -size +0c | rev |cut -d'.' -f1 |xargs -I % sed -n %p ../temp/files.2017-09-26.txt`

Comment: Still only 850. Here is the tar of the directories
[link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2B9TCXY80T4S2FTU2VRUmpXQXM?usp=sharing) @RomanPerekhrest latest edit seems to be getting the full 930.